# Java / MySQL: Inserting row into table from Java Web Application (TomCat v7.0)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, tomcat

Basically, I have two classes in my web application, one class 'FormProcess.java', which takes information inserting into an HTML form, performs a few calculations, then outputs the result as HTML. This works absolutely fine.

I also have a class for adding the data into a new row of a MySQL database, the class is called 'SqlConnect.java'. This also works fine if I run it seperately on the server (ie. it correctly inserts a row on to the table).

What I am struggling with is getting the SqlConnect methods to run from the FormProcess class. When I add the following to FormProcess:

```
private SqlConnect sql;
```

and in a method:

```
sql.doPost(request, response);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
crunch.FormProcess.doGet(FormProcess.java:27)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

This is the SqlConnect class at the moment (I left out the imports etc.):

```
@WebServlet(name="sql",urlPatterns={"/sql"})
public class SqlConnect extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    FormProcess process = new FormProcess();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SqlConnect() {

    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        performTask(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        performTask(request, response);
    }

    public void performTask(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        testJndiDataSource();
    }

    public void testJndiDataSource() {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/CrunchDB");

            conn = ds.getConnection();

            st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO log " + "VALUES (20, '1', '1', " + process.salaryInt + ", "+ process.takeHomePAYE +", "+ process.takeHomeContractor +", 2)");


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            try { if (st != null) st.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm sure there is a simple way of doing this I just can't work it out, as I said the SqlConnect class will run fine on it's own.

Cheers

Comment: Your query should like this than that may be work.....

"INSERT INTO log (COLUMN_NAME1,COLUMN_NAME2,COLUMN_NAME3,COLUMN_NAME4 ) " + "VALUES (20, '1', '1', " + process.salaryInt + ", "+ process.takeHomePAYE +", "+ process.takeHomeContractor +", 2)"

Comment: The problem doesn't lie in the query, it's in the way I am calling the method from FormProcess, as the query works fine on its own

Comment: Is FormProcess a servlet as well?

Comment: Yes FormProcess is a servlet

Comment: This is a chaining problem. http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Howto-call-a-Servlet-from-another-Servlet-Example-td2061954.html

Comment: Filters are the appropriate mechanism for what you are doing. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Comment: Okay using the link you posted for the chaining problem, I am now able to run SqlConnect from FormProcess, however the calculations performed on the data are not parsing through to it. ie. 'process.salaryInt' is coming through as 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38691/discussion-between-tom-haddad-and-emmentaler)

Comment: @TomHaddad: there's a better way to solve this problem that doesn't involve chaining or filters. See my answer below.

Comment: Agree with musical.  There is no good reason to create a separate servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the class structure you have right now is flawed. `SqlConnect` should not be a subclass of `HttpServlet`, because people should never be calling it directly as though it was a webpage. Instead, only `FormProcess` and your other actual servlets should access `SqlConnect`.

So now, your code should look something like this:

```
public void testJndiDataSource(int salaryInt, double takeHomePAYE, String takeHomeContractor) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/CrunchDB");

        conn = ds.getConnection();

        st = conn.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO log " + "VALUES (20, '1', '1', " + process.salaryInt + ", "+ process.takeHomePAYE +", "+ process.takeHomeContractor +", 2)");


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        try { if (st != null) st.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Then, in `FormProcess`:

```
public void performTask(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int salaryInt = //extract from form... 
    double takeHomePAYE = //extract from form... 
    String takeHomeContractor = //extract from form... 
    SqlConnect sqlConnect = new SqlConnect();
    sqlConnect.testJndiDataSource(salaryInt, takeHomePAYE, takeHomeContractor);
}
```

This is a much more logical approach to modeling how your site should work. Note: the query as it is right now is completely vulnerable to SQL injection. Change your `Statement` to a `PreparedStatement` per the instructions here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, however I am still getting this error: java.lang.NullPointerException, on the line where I call 'testJndiDataSource', not sure why this is the case?

Comment: Made a correction just now in `performTask()`; does that fix it?

Comment: Sorted it out myself, needed to remove the initialisation of FormProcess in SqlConnect, thanks a lot for your help!! :)